# Best way to restrict cloudpage access?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm in the process of building some reporting pages to allow insight into the data and to allow analysis for non-technical users. Essentially, I'm building a cloud page to display and allow for the same types of manipulation that one would typically use Excel for.

That being said, I don't want this information publicly accessible to anyone who happens to get the URL.

What is the best way to restrict access to a cloud page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own post because the answers here aren't really exactly what I chose to do.

I've decided to create a page that validates using a query string parameter - if the parameter is there and matches what's on file, the page loads. Otherwise, the page errors.

The strings are randomly generated and stored within a data extension. A full URL is concatenated and then passed to Sales Cloud through the API so that the non-technical users can access a list of page "reports" from Salesforce and simply click a link to get to the page.

This allows me to not have to ask the user for any additional piece of information (simply check the query parameter and load) and also keep things secure - the parameter is random and updated every so often - and updated in a way that doesn't force the user to have to know it.

In addition to this, I plan on also implementing an IP Whitelist as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cloudpage that uses an email address in a data extension to show a coupon code associated with that email address.

I might suggest having an email and password string within a data extension and revealing content based on that.  The ampscript is rather simple.

Drawback would be that you can easily change or delete values within data extension say if you wanted to restrict access or reset passwords.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method / function on cloud pages to restrict them as an Application Page.

I've wanted to do the same as you and raised with Salesforce the request as the old/classic version of Microsites used to allow you to restrict the page to ExactTarget application/logged in users.

You could contact your AE and ask for classic Microsites to be enabled on your account for this reason.

The usual safe harbour agreement from Salesforce implied there wasn't anything on the horizon to otherwise implement an Application Page in Cloud pages - a Shane really as it's a really handy feature